# Proof by induction, induction step

Tags: induction

I am trying to prove

$$
\sum_{k=1}^n k2^{k-1} = 1+(n-1)2^n
$$

I proved the base case with $n = 1$. I am having trouble proving the induction step.

I know I need to prove for $n = n +1$ so I got

$$
\sum_{k=1}^n k2^{k-1}+(k+1)2^{(k+1)-1} = 1+[(n+1)-1]2^{n+1}
$$

suppose $n = i$

$$
1 + [(i+1)-1]  2^{i+1}
$$

I am not sure if I am on the right path and how to simplify from here onwards? Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: OP: Please check that my LaTeX formatting coincides with your formulation of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}k2^{k-1}=
\biggl(\sum_{k=1}^{n}k2^{k-1}\biggr)+(n+1)2^{n+1-1}=
1+(n-1)2^{n}+(n+1)2^n
$$
Now we can finish it up:
$$
1+(n-1)2^{n}+(n+1)2^n=1+(n-1+n+1)2^n=
1+2n\cdot 2^n=1+n2^{n+1}
$$
and the statement you had to prove is exactly
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}k2^{k-1}=1+n2^{n+1}
$$
(just substitute $n$ with $n+1$ in the original formula).

---

You had $k$ in the term you pushed out of the summation, which is wrong.

Comment: Just to clarify, 1+(n-1)2^{n}+(n+1)2^n does show that it holds for n+1?

Comment: I am a little confused on how to go from here. Do I need to simplify 1+(n-1)2^{n}+(n+1)2^n more. Does the induction prove that it hold true for all positive numbers? Sorry I am a little new to induction

Comment: @RajKulao I added the complete steps

Comment: Makes a lot more sense. That you very much